# How to merge 2 shapefiles and averaging one of them that contains 19 fields in R?

Tags: r

I am new in R coding and I want to merge two shapefiles. The first one has 4 fields and the second one 19 of them. I would like to merge both but averaging the 19 fields from the second one and get the third field from the first one.

The webpage where the second one is available is here if you want to know https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/grump-v1-urban-ext-polygons-rev02/data-download

Can you please say me if it is possible and how to perform to achieve that aim?

I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you share an example of the two datasets using `dput()`?

Comment: Even though I use dput(data[3,5]) the output is too big and the space here can not host such code :(

Comment: Add the output to your question

Comment: The output will be one single shapefile containing the third field from the first shapefile and the average from the 19 fields from the second shapefile :)

Comment: We can help you if you can share your data with us

Comment: Tks, I will try again to share the data, but it is huge and even by using dput is larger than the box text can host

Comment: the dput can not get that global shapefile.
Is that part suitable for you to understand my first file?
Reading layer `level3' from data source `C:\Users\Bruna\Dropbox\My PC (LTOM-University-L)\Documents\Project_Global\level3.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 369 features and 4 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -180 ymin: -90 xmax: 180 ymax: 83.62361
geographic CRS: WGS 84

Comment: The second one is:
Reading layer `global_urban_extent_polygons_v1.01' from data source `C:\Users\Bruna\Dropbox\My PC (LTOM-University-L)\Documents\Project_Global\level3.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 75445 features and 19 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -179.525 ymin: -54.858 xmax: 179.6333 ymax: 78.27461
geographic CRS: WGS 84